# How to scroll down on a multi-line textbox downloaded as a pdf?

Tags: pdf, textbox, expandable

I have filled an official government form online. At the end instead of a "submit" button I was requested to email the form. When downloading the form it opened as a pdf on my computer. However, while the online form had text boxes that expand as you add text, the pdf only shows the collapsed text boxes, meaning half of the text is invisible. How can I view all the text?

I was expecting to see all my text I wrote in the textbox on the pdf but you can't scroll down. I tried to search for advice on Google but found none.

Comment: As we neither have the original form in question nor your downloaded copy, how should we tell?